# searching for a keyword in all the pods/replicas of a kuberntes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am running a deployment called *mydeployment* that manages several pods/replicas for a certain service. I want to search all the service pods/instances/replicas of that deployment for a certain keyword. The command below defaults to one replica and returns the keyword matching in this replica only.

```
Kubectl logs -f deploy/mydeployment | grep "keyword"
```

Is it possible to customize the above command to return all the matching keywords out of all instances/pods of the deployment *mydeployment*? Any hint?

Comment: You can use shell script, first fetch all the pods using kubectl get pods -A and then for each issue the kubetl log.. command.

Answer (score 1):

Save this to a file `fetchLogs.sh` file, and if you are using Linux box, use `sh fetchLogs.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

podName="key-word-from-pod-name"
keyWord="actual-log-search-keyword"
nameSpace="name-space-where-the-pods-or-running"
echo "Running Script.."
for podName in `kubectl get pods -A -o name | grep -i ${podName} | cut -d'/' -f2`;
do
       echo "searching pod ${podName}"
       kubectl -n ${nameSpace} logs pod/${podName} | grep -i ${keyWord}
done
```

I used the pods, if you want to use deployment, the idea is same change the `kubectl` command accordingly.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. What modifications to the script  are recommended so that (1) the required logs/keywords are returned in stream mode  (the deployment is in execution), and (2) if i want to search in stream mode the start and completion time of each pod of the deployment.

Comment: Not sure how that can be done, but if the shell script is made executable, probably you can use watch command which runs the script every 2 seconds (that time is also configurable.)